# on_success for jobs in protected environments is ignored

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

`prod` is configured as a [protected environment](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/protected_environments.html). After approval of deploy job I would like to run tests automatically to verify successful deployment.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy"
  environment:
    name: prod
    action: start
    
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test"
  environment:
    name: prod
    action: verify
  when: on_success
```

The `.gitlab.ci` template above will generate the following pipeline:

[image: pipeline]

After approving the deployment to `prod` the test job still require a manual action. Why is that? How do you run automated tests using `environment` and `action: verify`?

Removing the `environment` section from the test job gives the desired funcitonality, but this defeats the purpose of `action: verify`?

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploy"
  environment:
    name: prod
    action: start
    
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test"
  when: on_success
```